# How to resolve CocoaPods error when making a Flutter application for iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I am making a Flutter application, and the code was working fine but during a hot reload it started showing this error.

> Warning: CocoaPods is installed but broken. Skipping pod install.
> You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.   This
> can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is
> different from the one being used to invoke it.   This can usually be
> fixed by re-installing CocoaPods. To re-install see
> https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation
> for instructions.
>
> CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state. Error launching
> application

Answer (score 0):

Using following commands

- sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
- sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
- cocoapods pod install